# URL parameter not preserved after validation fails and 'new' action is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I initially call the new function all variables load up correctly. The params[:code] is a URL param defined in routes. However, when validation fails on create and new is rendered, the @m variable is not loaded (this causes a nomethoderror when an attribute of @m is called in the 'new' template). So, the :code parameter is not obtained after rendering new. However can the :code parameter be preserved after validation fails?

```
     class AffiliatesController < ApplicationController

        def new
          @m = Merchant.find_by_code(params[:code])
          @affiliate = Affiliate.new
        end


        def create
          a = Affiliate.new(params[:affiliate])
          if a.save
             redirect_to 'http://' + params[:ref]
          else
             render 'new'
          end
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to preserve `params[:code]`, aside from using the session, is to add a hidden field in the form.

```
<%= form_for @affiliate do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :code, @m.code %>
```

Then change the create action to

```
def create
  @affiliate = Affiliate.new(params[:affiliate])

  if @affiliate.save
    redirect_to 'http://' + params[:ref]
  else
    @m = Merchant.find_by_code(params[:code])
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

before you call `render` you should fill in all the variables that will be used by the view.
So in your case you need to instantiate `@m = ...` *before* you `render 'new'` from within the `create` as well.

If you need an extra parameter to accomplish this (the `param[:code]` in your case) I would not recomment you to configure routes and pass this information over the URI, it's complicated.

Use the session instead, it's a lot easier!

For example:
in `index` (or wherever you have the merchant code available) add `session[:merchant_code] = the_code`.

in `new` change `@m = Merchant.find_by_code(session[:merchant_code])`

Cheers,